# how to use jQuery Selector for multi values by one classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i know it might sound a bit of a beginner's question
but imagine i have the following example

```
  <div class = "image">content 1</div>
  <div class = "image">content 2</div>
  <div class = "image">content 3</div>
```

and i want to use jquery to get an array of the values like in vanilla JavaScript we would use

`let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("image");`

However, if i try to use `var img = $('.image').val();`  it will return the last value only,
i also checked the general attributes page by [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/general-attributes/) and i cant find it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered using [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)

```
var image = {};
    $(".image").each(function(index) {
        image[index] = $(this).val();
    });
```